# Java Pre assign args before passing from command line

Tags: java, args

I am developing a very simple Java application, through which to take files from a folder, obtain information from them and save them in the database.

The app is launched from the command line, and I need to pass the following parameters: `file_path, db_name, db_user, db_host, db_user_psw`.

When I run the check to see if all the parameters have been passed, in case a parameter is missing, I get an index out of bound exception, correctly according to java.
My need is to bypass this exception and display a string indicating an error message.

For example, if all parameters except `db_user_psw` are entered, instead of getting index of bound exception I would like the message `"You must enter the password to access the db!"`.

My idea is to pre-assign the args to null, and once the script is run check if they are null or not.
Is it possible to do this in java? I accept any advice or suggestion

- My code:

```
if(args[0] == null ){ System.out.println("Insert a valid Path!"); System.exit(0); }
if(args[1] == null ){ System.out.println("Insert the DB IP!"); System.exit(0);}
if(args[2] == null ){ System.out.println("Insert a DB name!"); System.exit(0);}
if(args[3] == null ){ System.out.println("Insert a DB Username!"); System.exit(0);}
if(args[4] == null ){ System.out.println("Insert User DB Password!"); System.exit(0);}
```

Comment: ***Is it possible to do this in java?*** Why don't you try it and check for yourself? Or do you face any issues if you have already tried?

Comment: Also, is maven tag relevant w.r.t. this question? If not, can you please remove it?

Comment: Perhaps you would be better served by using something like JCommander https://jcommander.org/ (no affiliation) instead. This would make your program much more robust, enable self-documentation, and not require arguments to be in a specific order.

Answer (score 1):

> When I run the check to see if all the parameters have been passed, in case a parameter is missing, I get an index out of bound exception, correctly according to java. My need is to bypass this exception and display a string indicating an error message.

Check the length of `args` instead:

```
if(args.length == 0){ System.out.println("Insert a valid Path!"); System.exit(0); }
if(args.length == 1){ System.out.println("Insert the DB IP!"); System.exit(0);}
// ...
```

(You should exit with a non-zero code, in order to indicate an error)

I think you should really consider using named flags, so your command line isn't just a "meaningless" sequence of arguments that can easily be put in the wrong order. So rather than

```
java YourMainClass whatever blah etc
```

you provide something like:

```
java YourMainClass --file_path=whatever --db_name=blah etc
```

---

For your specific question of "Is it possible to do this in java?": You can, by copying the args array:

```
if (args.length < 5) args = Arrays.copyOf(args, 5);
// or
args = Arrays.copyOf(args, Math.max(5, args.length));
```

If `args` has fewer than 5 elements, this will create an array with 5 elements, padding the "missing" elements with null.

But this is an odd and unnecessary thing to do: checking the length is easier.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure on this, since I am a beginner myself but did you consider to wrap it into a `try` - `catch` block?

````
try {
  //  Your logic to execute
}
catch(Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Insert User DB Password! " + e);
// or something else
}```
````

Comment: Don't use exceptions to handle things you can detect by other means: you can determine that there aren't enough args simply by checking the length of the array. Exceptions are very heavyweight compared to an `if` statement, and also don't necessarily catch the problem you _think_ you're catching. Additionally, you _almost never_ want to catch `Exception`, but instead a more specific exception.